# Using Unity3D to render a character onto a Kinect WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, kinect, zigfu

I am working on a project which requires me to render a virtual character onto the kinect video feed in which the player appears.

I am attempting to use Unity3D to accomplish this. I have looked at Zigfu but I don't think this directly helps. I still want to be able to send data from my C# WPF program to the game engine (I am forking my project off from kinect Fusion Explorer). Ideally Unity would be rendering the character and movement, my WPF program would be sending information to Unity about the landscape and running the Kinect feed.

Has anyone attempted this or have any idea how this could be achieved?

If this is not possible with Unity, are there other game dev libraries I could use to render a character onto the Kinect feed?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use Kinect Fusion or only gets joints position&rotation?

Comment: I'm using Kinect Fusion to scan the room and get a 3D mesh of the space.

I will then use that to tell the character where to move, so that it doesn't collide into objects and furniture.

Comment: I can't say so much thing. Maybe your wpf app sends info on network and your unity app listens it and renders it. But i think it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data via network (sockets) you will face problems with the size of frames. So my opinion is to use WCF. I'm not sure if it works for you, but this's how I managed it in my project (sending position and orientation)